# Program, Account, Publickey and Keypair in Anchor

Tags: rust, anchor, solana, anchor-solana, solana-program-library

I'm beginner of solana programming using anchor. Now I have no clear understanding about these items.

```
 **Program, Account, PublicKey, Keypair**
```

Appreciate any help to understand what these are and relationship between each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these terms can be found in the terminology section of the Solana docs at https://docs.solana.com/terminology

- Program: The code that interprets instructions.
- Account: A record in the Solana ledger that either holds data or is an executable program.
- PublicKey: The public key of a keypair.
- Keypair: A public key and corresponding private key for accessing an account.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://solanacookbook.com/ and the `Core Concepts` Section